# how to get grid-area's real size in Grid layout

Tags: css, layout, grid, height, width

### editted

the reason why I cannot get the grid-area's height and width is that I am using Vue as my UI framework, and it will group web changes together as one tick.

my current solution is to get grid-area's height and width in Vue.nextTick, which resolve the problem.

### original question

as title, since several grid can be grouped as a whole grid-area, how to get the specific grid-area's size? What can I get is only the grid item's height and width.

the only way is to calculate it by its span? is there any other way more directly?

[several initial separated grids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa62Y.png)

[group first 4 grids as grid-area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KPAv.png)

[what it looks like in dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hEyU.png)

Comment: By “size”, do you mean “area”? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the "size" here means "grid-area" 's height and width